# Line breaks in streetAddress AD attribute not shown on MySite

Tags: mysite, ad

We currently use the AD attributes `co`, `st`, `streetAddress`, `l` etc. to hold a user's address data. Even though streetAddress is not a multivalue attribute in AD, you can enter multiple lines, simply separated by `\r\n`.
When synchronized to sharepoint, the linebreaks don't show within the MySite display (although they do survive within the HTML).
Since the address attributes are also shown within Outlook, using HTML is not an option.

Is there any way to get a multiple line streetAddress attribute value to display as multiple lines in MySite?